# How do I prepare for segue to load different arrays in my TableViewController?

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift, uitableview

After days of struggling I can't figure out how to fix this. I am making a simple restaurant app. The `foodMenuController` contains 2 buttons which have to load different menu arrays into a `tableViewController` (lunch,breakfast). To define what menu should be loaded I was told by someone to use a `variable -> contentMode`.

In my `TableViewController` i set the `contentMode` to `"0"`. In my `foodMenuController` i used prepare for segue with a identifier to set the `contentMode` to `1` (breakfast) and `2` (lunch).

Now the problem is that my table does not know when it is in contentMode 1 or 2 nor do I know where and how to write the code to indicate the table to load different arrays when in a certain contentMode. I hope someone can help me with the code i published below.

```
import UIKit

class foodMenuController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
            let foodMenuController = segue.destinationViewController as! foodTableViewController

            if segue.identifier == "showBreakfast" {
                foodMenuController.contentMode = 1
            } else if segue.identifier == "showBakery" {
                foodMenuController.contentMode = 2
            }
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

---

```
import UIKit

class foodTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var foodItem: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var foodDescription: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var foodPrice: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

---

```
import UIKit

class foodTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    // Content Mode Selection in menu
    var contentMode = 0

    // THIS SHOULD BE LOADED WHEN CONTENT MODE is "1" --> BREAKFAST
    var foodItems = ["Bread", "Coffee", "Nada"]
    var foodInfo = ["Good", "Nice", "Nothing"]
    var foodPrice = ["$1", "$100", "$12,40"]

    // THIS SHOULD BE LOADED WHEN CONTENT MODE IS "2" --> LUNCH
    var foodItems = ["Not bread", "Not Coffee", "Something"]
    var foodInfo = ["Not good", "Not nice", "Yes"]
    var foodPrice = ["$1", "$100", "$12,40"]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // Table view data source
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return foodItems.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! foodTableViewCell

        cell.foodItem.text = foodItems[indexPath.row]
        cell.foodDescription.text = foodInfo[indexPath.row]
        cell.foodPrice.text = foodPrice[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a variable called `foodMenuController` inside a class called `foodMenuController` but the variable isn't a `foodMenuController` type.  I suggest cleaning up your naming (including capitalization) to avoid unnecessary confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the array names as shown below.

```
// THIS SHOULD BE LOADED WHEN CONTENT MODE is "1" --> BREAKFAST
let breakfastItems = ["Bread", "Coffee", "Nada"]
let breakfastInfo = ["Good", "Nice", "Nothing"]
let breakfastPrice = ["$1", "$100", "$12,40"]

// THIS SHOULD BE LOADED WHEN CONTENT MODE IS "2" --> LUNCH
let lunchItems = ["Not bread", "Not Coffee", "Something"]
let lunchInfo = ["Not good", "Not nice", "Yes"]
let lunchPrice = ["$1", "$100", "$12,40"]

var foodItems: [String] = []
var foodInfo: [String] = []
var foodPrice: [String] = []
```

Now check the value of contentMode in `ViewWillAppear`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    switch (contentMode){
    case 1:
        foodItems = breakfastItem
        foodInfo = breakfastInfo
        foodPrice = breakfastPrice
    case 2:
        foodItems = lunchItem
        foodInfo = lunchInfo
        foodPrice = lunchPrice
    default:
        break
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

This will copy the desired item, info ,price arrays into the foodItem, foodInfo and foodPrice arrays. The rest of your code will work fine and the `UITableView` will be populated as desired.

Comment: thanks! But where exactly do i put the code of viewWillAppear?

Comment: You must `override` the `viewWillAppear` method of `FoodTableViewController` class as shown.

Comment: Okay, the code is added and works fine but it's not loading any data into the tableView....any idea why?

Comment: check if the value set in the `prepareForSegue` method of `FoodMenuController` and `switch` in the `FoodTableViewController` are as desired. Or you can set breakpoints in `switch` to find which case is executed.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "switch"? I checked the segues and they are correct... it just keeps showing a blank Tableview.. Where do I go from here? or should i post a new question for this?

Comment: I mentioned the `switch` block in my answer posted above. The data to be populated in the `UITableView` is determined based on the value of `contentMode` in this `switch` block. Probably that might be the one you are missing. So the value you set for `contentMode` from `prepareForSegue` must correspond to the values in `switch` block.

Comment: I just checked the prepare for segue and switch block and they correspond.. the first button with a prepare for segue is content mode 1 and the second is content mode 2.. I posted a new question with this issue so you can see what i did or if i am missing something.... --> [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325709/why-is-my-tableviewcontroller-not-loading-any-data)

Comment: So you have got either of the switch cases (1 or 2) executed when the `FoodTableViewController` is instantiated and not the default case. Just make sure the value of `contentMode` is set right. You may do this by printing the value of `contentMode` or setting a break point in the `viewWillAppear` of `FoodTableViewController`. The only possibility I see is `contentMode` is still 0. Check if the `segue` Identifiers are correct.

Comment: I checked the segue and it still prints "0" as the contentMode. I checked both identifiers and they are correct so where does the problem lie? should I upload the file so you can check??

Comment: Yeah please do the same

Comment: Here is the link to file --> [ https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwG7uhSgLIvWdkxiS2JER0hucmM ]