# Why is my tableViewController not loading any data?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, tableview

Im creating an app where different buttons in a ViewController load different menu's into the tableViewController. The buttons are linked by a prepare for segue and the menu's (arrays) are linked by a contentMode. 1: breakfast menu & 2: lunch menu. I had allot of help from someone setting this up but now the table is not loading any data... The cell has 3 labels which display an item, info and price. It changes value within the code when a contentMode is selected. Does anyone see the problem in my code? thanks a lot!

```
import UIKit

class foodMenuController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
let foodMenuController = segue.destinationViewController as! foodTableViewController

  if segue.identifier == "showBreakfast" {
            foodMenuController.contentMode = 1
    } else if segue.identifier == "showLunch" {
        foodMenuController.contentMode = 2
        }
    }


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

---

```
import UIKit

class foodTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var foodItem: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var foodDescription: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var foodPrice: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

---

```
import UIKit

class foodTableViewController: UITableViewController {

//Content Mode Selection in menu
var contentMode = 0

// THIS SHOULD BE LOADED WHEN CONTENT MODE is "1" --> BREAKFAST
let breakfastItems = ["Bread", "Coffee", "Nada"]
let breakfastInfo = ["Good", "Nice", "Nothing"]
let breakfastPrice = ["$1", "$100", "$12,40"]

// THIS SHOULD BE LOADED WHEN CONTENT MODE IS "2" --> LUNCH
let lunchItems = ["Not bread", "Not Coffee", "Something"]
let lunchInfo = ["Not good", "Not nice", "Yes"]
let lunchPrice = ["$1", "$100", "$12,40"]

var foodItems: [String] = []
var foodInfo: [String] = []
var foodPrice: [String] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    }

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    switch (contentMode){
    case 1: contentMode = 1
        foodItems = breakfastItems
        foodInfo = breakfastInfo
        foodPrice = breakfastPrice
    case 2: contentMode = 2
        foodItems = lunchItems
        foodInfo = lunchInfo
        foodPrice = lunchPrice
    default:
        break
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}

// Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:
        Int) -> Int {
        return foodItems.count

}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! foodTableViewCell

    cell.foodItem.text = foodItems[indexPath.row]
    cell.foodDescription.text = foodInfo[indexPath.row]
    cell.foodPrice.text = foodPrice[indexPath.row]

        return cell


    }
}
```

---

Comment: If you got this question answered then you should probably mark it and close it. Its already a duplicate one. Don't leave it open. Also please note what was the missing point. Also ensure you are following the universal naming standards. The `class` names must start with uppercase character.

Comment: Im sorry @Mathews but i have been dealing with this issue for far too long so I am just anxious to fix it. However, I just printed the value and it does come back as contentMode "0" so i will have to see where the problem lies.

Comment: So please have a look at the `prepareForSegue` method in the `FoodMenuViewController`.  if the segue Identifiers are wrong, it will not set the `contentMode` as desired.

Comment: @Mathews - Checked the prepareForSegue identifiers in the storyboard and the code, both the same....So i seriously have no clue why it is not changing the contentMode to 1?...

btw thanks though you have been a great help so far! i just want this to work....

Comment: Please can you do upload the` xcodeProject` file. It will be helpful in debugging.

Comment: For those who want to take a look I'm very curious to find out what is going on.... Here is the link to file --> [ drive.google.com/open?id=0BwG7uhSgLIvWdkxiS2JER0hucmM ]

Comment: You haven't granted permissions to view the file

Comment: @Mathews - sorry! just made it public [link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwG7uhSgLIvWdkxiS2JER0hucmM/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made slight modifications in your project.
1. make the `UINavigationController` the `InitialViewController`
2. make the `FoodMenuController` the root of `UINavigationController`
[image: StoryBoard]

Now modify your `FoodMenuController`

```
@IBOutlet weak var bakeryButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var breakfastButton: UIButton!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true //hide navigationBar in first ViewController
    self.bakeryButton.addTarget(self, action: "bakeryButtonAction:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    self.breakfastButton.addTarget(self, action: "breakfastButtonAction:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
}

func bakeryButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("showLunch", sender: self)
}

func breakfastButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("showBreakfast", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let foodTableViewController: FoodTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! FoodTableViewController

    if segue.identifier == "showBreakfast" {
        foodTableViewController.contentMode = 1
    } else if segue.identifier == "showLunch" {
        foodTableViewController.contentMode = 2
    }
}
```

Also you can make `UINavigationBar` visible in `FoodTableViewController`

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
    }
```

PS: It is always better not to add segue directly to a `UIButton`. Alternatively you can add it from the yellow button on top of your `FoodMenuController` and specify the segue to be fired in `UIButtonAction` using `performSegueWithIdentifier`

Comment: Thanks a million dude!!!! Finally it works..Could you explain in short why though? Else i'm just copying stuff.. And you are saying I should change the prepare for segue to perform segue and give the button an identifier?

Comment: Thats not correct.
1. `PerformSegueWithIdentifier`: This when executed will fire the `segue` with the given identifier. The `PrepareForSegue` method is executed next.
 2.`PrepareForSegue`: This method is overridden to configure the data to be passed on a `segue`.
Instead of direct `segue` you can add segue from the `ViewController` to the destination. Now create `outlets` for the `UIButton`s and add actions for the buttons

Comment: Now if the answer is satisfactory mark it an answer so that the question is closed.

Comment: I will modify the above answer with `performSegueWithIdentifier` integrated.
 You have to delete current segues and add them from the yellow icon on ViewController

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything apparently wrong with the snippet you shared. You can check what is returned in the `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method and see if it is returning a value > 0

Also, this is a given but we've all done it at some point of time - check to make sure the tableview delegate and datasource are set to your viewcontroller.

Comment: He is already subclassing `UITableViewController `; view hierarchy as well as delegate/data source _should_ be wired appropriately (unless he accidentally unwired it). So that should pretty much leave `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`...?

Comment: I checked the segue identifiers and they are correct... the data is still not loading? what am I missing here? anyone has an idea? don't want to repost the question... this is just getting ridiculous if not even the experts know what is going on... should i upload the file?

Comment: @Kevin like I said, there is nothing apparently wrong with the code. Did you check whether `numberOfRowsInSection:` is getting the correct count after you do a `reloadData` in `viewWillAppear:`? That might give you a hint

Comment: @lostInTransit - Im very thankful for your help! but by now it must be clear to you i am a absolute NOOB at programming. I am still learning the why's and how's and although it may seem obvious to you i am missing something in the numberOfRowsInSection: ... I have no clue what the hint is..cause i don't know how to check for the count... :(

Comment: Debug through the program, put in a breakpoint in the method and check what `foodItems.count` has

Answer (score 0):

I can no where see you setting the datasource and delegate of the tableView, please cross check these are both setup.

Comment: The controller class is already subclassing `UITableViewController`. So the `dataSource` and `delegate` are wired to the controller class by default. See the comment of @Nicolas

Comment: I tried your code. It works without any issue. I am attaching the xcode project with your code. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwftp_LIDNUQcTd2cXA0TVB2THc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks. But still you are using a `UITableView` inside a `UIViewController`. In the question we are dealing with a `UITableViewController`. So we needn't bother about `dataSource` and `delegate`. All those are taken care of by the `UITableViewController` itself.

Comment: No no .. Tapping on the cell will take you to the tableviewcontroller class